# docker-compose run mysql: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql5

I'm totally roasted after working 14 hours straight, and even after crawling the whole internet I'm unable to resolve this problem.

The scene is imaginable simple:

I have a `docker-compose.yml` with many services required to install and deploy an app, amongst them a simple **MySQL 5** service:

```
  (...)
  mysql:
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
    image: mysql:5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  (...)
```

Now I just want to create the initial database before deploying the app, with a simple:

```
docker-compose run mysql mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database"
```

But whatever I try I get this error:

```
Creating network "app_default" with the default driver
Creating app_mysql_run ... done
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I also tried (without success / with the same error message):

```
docker-compose up -d mysql
docker-compose exec mysql mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database"
```

The only thing that works is entering the container and **manually** executing the **exact(!) same(!)** command. But I absolutely need to automate it.

What am I missing? Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to run with `docker-compose exec mysql mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb"` ? If you use `run`, you will need to specify the host in the command as `run` will create another container to communicate with the other container.

Comment: If you use `run`, the command will be like `docker-compose run mysql mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb" -h 172.26.0.2` where `172.26.0.2` should be replaced with your mysql container ip

Comment: @MicFung Thanks for your input, unfortunately I already tired both without success. Also, when executing `exec` or `run`, I expect the command being executed inside the container, not the host.

Comment: weird. for the host, i mean the mysql host which means the IP actually. The run or exec will run the command inside the container. As the run command will create another container, the mysql cannot be connected directly so IP needs to be specified. From what I see, you are able to run the command under bash mode so can you try `docker-compose exec mysql /bin/bash -c "mysql -e \"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS abc\""`

Comment: I figured it out, but I'm not satisfied with my "solution". It seems that `run` overwrites the entrypoint, so `mysqld` isn't there. With `exec`, I run into a race condition when I `up` the host container and then `exec` my command. A working "solution" is `sleep` before `exec`. The problem I have with that is I can't just expect the start time of `mysqld` being the same on all machines. An acceptable solution would be to pass multiple commands to start `mysqld` before running the command, but that doesn't seem to work at all. Meh...

Comment: I think for this situation, you need to create your own Dockerfile on top of mysql to execute the command you want after start up. Or make a shell script to loop the condition of mysql and execute the command after the database is up

Comment: Thanks for your support! I found a satisfiable solution and ended up using a while loop inside the container, detaching the output for cleanliness and using `IF NOT EXISTS` to prevent a deadlock if the database already exists: `docker compose exec mysql /bin/bash -c "while ! mysql -e \"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database\" &> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `docker-compose run` and `docker-compose exec` overwrite the commands of the Dockerfile, thus `mysqld` is never started. Passing `mysqld && mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE database"` doesn't work, and running `docker-compose exec` after `docker-compose up` will result in a race condition.

I ended up with the following solution, which suits my needs:

```
docker-compose run mysql && \
docker-compose exec mysql /bin/bash -c "while ! mysql -e \"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database\" &> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done"
```

This will loop the command on a child container until the host container is ready. Also, `IF NOT EXISTS` is important here, otherwise it may run into a deadlock if the database already exists.